# .htaccess issue, folder in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder called /mf/ that is not related to the wordpress install but it is in the same root folder. When I visit the folder path (www.domain.com/mf) it gives me a 500 error. I know that this is an .htaccess issue.

I've modded my root .htaccess to do the below code but it still does not work:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mf/(.*)$ [OR]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
 </IfModule>


 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

Any advice on how to fix this .htaccess issue?

Comment: Why an `[OR]` flag on the last condition? I doubt that is valid syntax.

Comment: @Sumurai8 i saw it in a reference doc, any suggestions on the correct syntax?

Comment: The `[OR]` flag implies that "if this condition is not met, do not stop processing this rule but check if the next condition is met". However, there is no next rule. You should remove that flag.

Comment: @Sumurai8 i've removed the OR flag. Still does not work properly unfortuantely. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: What does the apache error log say in that case?

Comment: @Sumurai8 error_log in both my wordpress and /mf/ folder says nothing. just visiting the url www.domain.com/mf gives me a 404 on my wordpress website. even though it shouldn't be related.

Comment: Remember that you are using `/mf/` as a base. The url should contain at least that final slash for the first part to match, which is required to prevent the second rule to match, which will route things through wordpress.

Comment: @Sumurai8 do you have any documentation you can provide? i'm a bit confused

Comment: [The mod-rewrite tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info) and [this canonical answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/214512/203349) tells you a lot. Also [the official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). What I am saying is that www.domain.com/mf does not trigger the first rule, because `^/mf/(.*)$` does not match `/mf` in that url. The final slash is missing.

Comment: @Sumurai8 i see. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your "mf" folder create a .htaccess file and there put all the configuration that nedded, and in the main folder-wordpress put only the wordpress part.

in th "mf" change the **RewriteBase** too.

main-wordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

the mf folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /mf/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mf/(.*)$ [OR]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, i realized the mod_rewrite should also be in the /mf/ folder. it works now.